# Handle specific image response by javascript

Tags: javascript, image

```
<img src="/a.jpg" onerror="fetch(\'/a.jpg\')
    .then(code => console.log(code === 499
        ? 'image will be available in a moment'
        : 'image not found'))">
```

Is it possible to do this without firing two HTTP requests (one by `img.src` and one by `fetch` function)?

My use case is I want to fire a polling loop (which I have already implemented, just skipped it there for simplicity) that will retry loading the image if it is still being prepared on server (the loop will of course fire more HTTP requests, but that's OK), but if the image actually does not exist, just show "image not found".

The server can be implemented for example this way:

- if an image exists and has a thumbnail ready, return an image response
- if an image exists but thumbnail is not ready yet, return specific HTTP code (499)

Compatibility with modern browsers & IE 11 is enough for me.

Comment: Could you create something that serves up the images smartly? For example, instead of requesting `/image-cache/thumbs/12345.jpg`, point your `<img>` tags at `/image-server/thumb?id=12345`. Have this server-side `thumb` method check if the image physically exists and return its byte array (and set the response type to "image/jpeg"), and if not, serve back a 404 or a dummy image. You could add caching if necessary.

Comment: _"technically unnecessary"_. I don't get this? Ajax is a callback function. So it just sends the request and moves on. Waiting for your server to "call" it again when it's ready. Once the server is finished, it returns "ready" to your ajax and ajax loads the image. Instead of verifying whether the image is there or not periodically, it just tells your server to let it know when it's there.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question a bit. @Cᴏʀʏ it is already served by PHP, that's not the problem. The problem is to distinguish 404 from 'preview not ready yet'.
@icecub Your suggestion would mean keeping an open HTTP connection for each thumbnail on the page. That's why I'd rather replace this by polling. But by "technically unnecessary" I mean that displaying an image by assigning the url to `<img src>` and getting HTTP status code by AJAX request means at least two HTTP requests for every image that was not found or waiting for thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution myself - **load the image using XHR and display it using BLOB API**.

This solution provides all what I wanted:

- fires only single HTTP request to get an `{image|error code}`,
- does not need additional user permissions (like implementation with webRequest hook),
- does not pollute DOM with extra long base64 urls,
- seems compatible with modern browsers and even IE10.

---

```
var myImage = document.querySelector('img');

var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
myRequest.open('GET', 'http://placekitten.com/123/456', true);
myRequest.responseType = 'blob';
myRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (myRequest.readyState !== 4) {
        return;
    }
    if (myRequest.status === 200) {
        var blob = myRequest.response;
        var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // this is the trick - generates url like 
        // blob:http://localhost/adb50c88-9468-40d9-8b0b-1f6ec8bb5a32
        myImage.src = objectURL;
    } else if (myRequest.status === 499) {
        console.log('... waiting for thumbnail');
        retryAfter5s(); // implementation of retry loop is not important there
    } else {
        console.log('Image not found');
    }
};
myRequest.send();
```

Comment: @Raymond it is not true, you never mentioned using Blob nor provided an equivalent solution. You were just repeating something about a loop that - as you can see - is really not important in this question, and your suggestions like catching XHR requests or using webRequest API did not work, were still firing multiple requests or requiring additional permissions. You were not helpful, you were just trying something you obviously did not understand in your chase for reputation, wasted 2 hours of my life by turning in loops then when I finally explained you the point, you got offended.